# How to translate a SOAP XML Request to PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I need to send the soap request with PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Common" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:SaveThePayment>
      <ns2:reglement>
        <ns1:CENTRE>330</ns1:CENTRE>
        <ns1:CLIENT>00800808782</ns1:CLIENT>
        <ns1:EXIGIBILITE>25/03/19</ns1:EXIGIBILITE>
        <ns1:MONTANT>1000</ns1:MONTANT>
        <ns1:NUMFACTURE>787322</ns1:NUMFACTURE>
        <ns1:ORDRE>01</ns1:ORDRE>
        <ns1:PERIODE>201902</ns1:PERIODE>
      </ns2:reglement>
      <ns2:plateforme>?</ns2:plateforme>
    </ns2:SaveThePayment>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is how I did in PHP

```
class MakeIt
{
    protected $url = "https://server_ip:port?wsdl";

    public function makeItHere()
    {
        $reglement = new ReferenceReglement();
        $reglement->CENTRE = "330";
        $reglement->CLIENT = "00800808782";
        $reglement->EXIGIBILITE = "25/03/19";
        $reglement->MONTANT = 3000.00;
        $reglement->NUMFACTURE = "787322";
        $reglement->ORDRE = "01";
        $reglement->PERIODE = "201902";

        $clientSoap = new SoapClient($this->url);
        // dd($clientSoap->__getTypes());
        $response = $clientSoap->__soapCall("SaveThePayment", [
            "reglement" => $reglement,
            // "plateforme" => ""
        ]);

        dd($response);
    }
}

class ReferenceReglement
{
    public $CENTRE;
    public $CLIENT;
    public $ORDRE;
    public $NUMFACTURE;
    public $PERIODE;
    public $MONTANT;
    public $EXIGIBILITE;
}
```

Here is the error I get

SoapFault
The server could not process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, enable IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior ) on the server to return the exception information to the client, or enable tracking according to the Microsoft .NET Framework Software Development Kit (SDK) documentation and review the server's tracking logs.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to look at the logs in your soap client server.

Here the issue might be the argument type that you are passing for "reglement" which is an object. So check in the soap server if the argument type is same or not.

Comment: I do not have the access to server. I am using a web services.

Comment: This might help you. https://forums.asp.net/t/2072459.aspx?either+turn+on+IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults+either+from+ServiceBehaviorAttribute+or+from+the+serviceDebug+configuration+behavior+on+the+server and